# How to run Flask in two Port or threads

Tags: python, flask

I want to run a Flask instance that listens in two different ports, I mean, some operations at port 8080 and others at 8090. Is There any way to do this? O maybe running two Flask app instances in thread?

Adding Context: Basically, I need to emulate a production envs, in which the core functionality is on port 8080, but since some security restriction I need to use a proxy for some operations (8090) for some specific clients

I mean on 8080 for instance

- /repository/{id}

This operation is consume by almost all clients, however, some specific client need to use a proxy.
on 8090 for instance

- /reposproxy?method="get"&resource="repository"&query="id="xxxx"

that basically, call the 8080.

Additionally, I try to fork or make a thread for app.run() but I could not succeeds to run.

Comment: could you explain some more about what you are tryign to accomplish? Why are you doing this? what operations should be taking place on 8080 opposed to 8090?

Comment: Just run two separate instances to do this. Separate the two services so that if one causes an un-handled error it does not ripple and close both services.

Comment: I tried running on 2 thread without success

Comment: Are you using ``app.run`` for this?

Comment: yes, but I only way I success only starting with with differents python execution. Is it possible to run in a single program?

Comment: Is there any reason they *need* to run in a single process?  If it is just convenience of starting the solution you can create a shell script or batch file that simply starts each of the services in their own shell.

Comment: You shouldn't use ``app.run`` in production, it's there for testing purposes.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved using a Fork(process) approach using multiprocessing python feature. I defined to app Flask and then run to process

```
def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', __name__)
    if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
        print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())


def startServer(inDebug, port):
    print "Starting Main Mock Server"
    app.run(debug=inDebug, port=port)


def startProxyServer(inDebug, port):
    print "Starting JSONP Mock Server Proxy"
    appJsonp.run(debug=inDebug, port=jsonpPort)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('Main Line Starting')
    p = mp.Process(target=startServer, args=(False, port))
    p.deamon = True
    p.start()
    p1 = mp.Process(target=startProxyServer, args=(False, port))
    p1.deamon = True
    p1.start()
    p.join()
    p1.join()
```

Comment: Clearly you didn't test this.